# Coredns dependency for dns service in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dns, coredns

I am a newbie to kubernetes. Do I need to install [core dns plugin](https://coredns.io/plugins/acl/)
separately if I already have coredns default pod running to have dns service implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**acl** is a internal plugin. It's already installed.

> There are currently about 30 plugins included in the default CoreDNS install, but there are also a whole bunch of external plugins that you can compile into CoreDNS to extend its functionality.

https://coredns.io/manual/plugins/#what-is-coredns

List of intenral plugins: https://coredns.io/plugins/